# Is meteor worth to be used in 2019 ? is it still alive?

Tags: meteor, status

I start to develop a new web application using meteor, but i noticed that the last update of meteor platform is from 2017 !!
so i became confused of its reliability.
is it dead?? 
or what is happen to meteor developing team?

Comment: Please go to forums.meteor.com to ask about the state of Meteor. There is a strong and supportive community behind it that will answer this question for you thoroughly. Please keep in mind that questions of this kind are not appropriate for Stack overflow. Please read the help section on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure it's not dead.
They keep rolling new updates: https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html

So the answer meteor is not dead.
Also, I suggest to use Meteor with React / Angular instead of Blaze. This will allow to migrate from meteor if you'll need it.

**Update:**

Recently Meteor got investment from [Tiny](https://www.tinycapital.com/). 
This will help maintainers to concentrate on meteor features and split it from GraphQl.
I think if it were dead nobody would invest in it.

[read on techcrunch](https://blog.meteor.com/a-new-chapter-for-meteor-7b684320be4c)

[read on meteor.com](https://techcrunch.com/2019/10/02/tiny-acquires-meteor/)

Comment: thanks so much.
the change-log is what i'm searching for.

Comment: The Angular port isn't well supported, I would recommend going with React, as that is a first class citizen.

Comment: I agree it's not dead. However, mobile App support (and docs) is still very poor - e.g. they are bundled with old cordova versions and to get the mobile toolchain running it's not enough to just install the current versions of Android Studio and Xcode.

For a Webplatform only it's fine tough.

Comment: I'd say that it's pretty much dead. It's gone from just under 60 000 downloads in 2017 to 15 000 downloads this year. You certainly won't find much help if you need it. I wonder why they keep updating it?

Comment: Why learn meteor when you have vue and react... Probably it's not dead but there's more competitive things to learn.

Comment: @svelandiag meteor allows you to use vue and react https://guide.meteor.com/react.html https://guide.meteor.com/vue.html so they are not direct competitors

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely *not dead*. Meteor has been going strong and progress is being made.You can read about the latest changes in the [Roadmap](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/Roadmap.md). [1.9.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v191-2020-02-18) has been released a couple of days ago. You can find lots of Meteor community members at this [slack channel](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/organization#slack)